# Error running Cognitive Services Read Text container preview

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, read-text

When I am processing an image file, the container crashes with the following error message

`azureocr_1  | docker-entrypoint.sh: line 6:     9 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) KMP_BLOCKTIME=1 KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MODE=1 OMP_WAIT_POLICY=PASSIVE LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib64/libmklml_intel.so dotnet Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.OneOcr.2.0.dll SecurityPrototype=true $*
azureocr_azureocr_1 exited with code 132`

We run Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is an internal issue. [Rising a support ticket from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) will be a good way to solve it .

Comment: Azure support found the cause : CPU must be AVX V2 minimum

Comment: Hi @ChristianMaillard , glad to know your issue has been solved , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark my post as an answer to close this question . Thanks !